# Transparent color of Selection in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I want to check the numbers of the selected vector in the attribute table. In my setting, the following is my table after I selected some vectors. As you can see, I am not able to look at any values. What setting should I need to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I can help directly but but more context could help e.g version of QGIS, OS (seems Mac but version)?

Comment: I am using mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 and QGIS 3.10.13.

Comment: Did you apply a specific Windows style/theme to your Mac interface? QGIS depends from Qt that depends from system windows managers. It could be related. Did you also try to start QGIS using a completely QGIS clean profile e.g a new one? It's a way to be sure your issue is not related to non default configuration you've made or a plugin made later while installing.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I got a desirable result by changing the setting,

Comment: Glad you solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the setting for the following and got a desirable result.

QGIS > Preferences > General > UI Theme > Night Mapping (Originally default).

[image]