# QGIS - Can't see rows data but I can see the total number of rows in the attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I tried to download some shapefiles data from [here](https://idt2.regione.veneto.it/idt/downloader/download) and the layer is shown correctly, however when I open the attribute table I can see just the number of rows but not the rows themselves and when I click organize columns no fields are detected, any tip on how to see the data in the attribute table?

The version of QGIS I am using is from the arch Linux repositories and my OS is Manjaro Linux if this can help.

[image]

Comment: There should be a box at the lower left of the attribute table where you can toggle between showing selected features or all features.  Maybe you are set to only show selected features but no features are selected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent color of Selection in Attribute Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389471/transparent-color-of-selection-in-attribute-table) Related to your black theme I think

Comment: @GBG It is on the option "show all features" by default so that was not the problem

Comment: @ThomasG77 unfortunately that's not the case, i tried to change themes but with no luck, plus in the post you linked the author could actually see the rows but they were empty and i don't see even those in my case

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot in your question of https://idt2.regione.veneto.it/idt/downloader/download with selected options so we can get the exact same data source? Could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that the .shp file name was in uppercase while the .dbf file and the .shx file were not.

After renaming the files accordingly in lowercase the table is shown correctly.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have a filter on. I can't see your whole attribute table from the screenshot. But, if you go through that dropdown menu in the bottom left of the table and select *Field Filter* or *Advanced Filter (Expression)* you may notice you have one on, or an expression set. In your screenshot it shows Features Total: 382, Filtered 382. [General Tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#more-information-on-layers-and-groups-using-indicator-icon).
[image]

Comment: "Features Total: 382, Filtered 382" actually means "unfiltered". All 382 features _passed_ the filter. It confuses me sometimes too.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. There should be a .dbf file with the attributes in the same folder as the .shp file. If not, that's the problem. Download again.
2. Delete the layer from QGIS. Copy the .dbf file to another folder. Then drag the new copy into the layer panel in QGIS. You won't see a layer on the canvas, but you will see an icon for the table in the layer panel. Open its attribute table. If you see attributes but no information, it's a problem with QGIS (ie a display issue due to filtering etc).
3. Dark Theme - turn it off and check again
4. Download another area from the same site. A layer downloaded from that site does appear to work. Maybe yours has bad attribute data.